# How do I turn off the Sub-Selection Tool "A"?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, shapes, tools, shortcuts

Here is an image of the sub selection tool:

[image]

How do I unselect this tool after I am done using it to adjust the vector shape?

Comment: click on something empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I do in your particular case, when I'm done editing anchors with the <kbd>A</kbd> tool, I switch to a 'low action' tool by hitting either:

- <kbd>V</kbd> which is the 'normal' move tool, kind of like the default tool in Illustrator, or
- <kbd>H</kbd> which is the 'hand' tool, which does not affect anything on the artboard, instead just moves the current view around

Answer (score 3):

## Select another tool

---

or to merely unselect the selected art...

## Unselect All

<kbd>Command/Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>

Or `Select > Deselect`

Or just click *anywhere* else to deactivate the current selection.

---

The shortcut comes in *very* handy if you are zoomed in and there's really no "clear" area to click. But most often... I simply click a "blank" area in the document.

<sub>The shortcut also works in InDesign</sub>